# Can I access data of type passed to generic base class referencing the derived class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an abstract generic base class, from which 2 derived classes are created. The base class takes 2 types, and those two type are different for each of the derived classes.

I'd like to be able to write shared code that will allow me to access a method of one of the attributes on one of the passed types. I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class GenericBase<T, U> {

    private T oneType;
    private U secondType;

    public GenericBase() {}
    public GenericBase(T oneType, U secondType) {
        this.oneType = oneType;
        this.secondType = secondType;
    }

}
```

---

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class DerivedOne<C, C1> extends GenericBase<ClassOne, ClassTwo> {
    public DerivedOne(ClassOne classOne, ClassTwo classTwo) {
        super(classOne, classTwo);
    }

    private String dummyString;
    private String dummyName;

}
```

---

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class DerivedTwo extends GenericBase<ClassThree, ClassFour>{

    public DerivedTwo(ClassThree classThree, ClassFour classFour) {
        super(classThree, classFour);
    }

    private Integer num1;
    private Integer num2;

}
```

---

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassOne {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String address;

}
```

---

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ClassTwo {

    private String ssNumber;
    private String dob;

}
```

---

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassThree {

    private String someDescription;
    private int amount;

}
```

---

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ClassFour {

    private Integer salary;
    private String carModel;

}
```

Then if I instantiate the "type" classes and the derived classes, I'd like to be able to access a method from say the  class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GenericsTestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GenericsTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        ClassOne c1 = new ClassOne("Fred", 27, "123 main street");
        ClassTwo c2 = new ClassTwo("123-45-6789", "03/21/57");
        ClassThree c3 = new ClassThree("some description", 25);
        ClassFour c4 = new ClassFour(25000, "Forester");
        DerivedOne<ClassOne, ClassTwo> d1 = new DerivedOne<>(c1, c2);
        DerivedTwo d2 = new DerivedTwo(c3, c4);
        Integer val = func1(d2);

    
    
    }

    static Integer func1(GenericBase genericBase) {
        return genericBase.getSecondType().getSalary();  <-- doesn't know how to resolve symbol getSalary
    }
}
```

The reason I'm looking to do this is because there is some duplicated code in a method that exists in different classes that differs only by the derived class being passed in. So the method is defined using the generic base class, which knows nothing of the structure of the types used to create the derived classes.

Is there a way to handle this, or am I stuck with the duplicate code?

Thanks.

Comment: Your function uses `GenericBase` without type parameters. Use `GenericBase<?, ClassFour>` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an interface like HasSalary and have your ClassFour implements this method.

```
public interface HasSalary{
   Integer getSalary();
}
```

And delcare you method as

```
static Integer func1(GenericBase<?,? extends HasSalary> genericBase) {
    return genericBase.getSecondType().getSalary();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure whether I understood the question correctly, but can't you check which of the derived classes the input is with instance of, and then cast it accordingly?

Like this

```
public class Testing {
    public String s;

    public Testing(String s) {
        s = this.s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing test = new ext("abcdefg");
        if (test instanceof ext) {
            ((ext) test).testMethod();
        }
    }
}

class ext extends Testing {

    public ext(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `GenericBase::getSecondType`, there's really no way to know what type will be returned, so you can't call any methods other than those of Object. So this should be fine:

```
private static Integer func1(GenericBase genericBase) {
    Object obj = genericBase.getField1();
    return obj.hashCode()
}
```

If you do want to call other methods, you'll have to ensure they are actually available on `genericBase`. You could do that by changing your `GenericBase` class:

```
public class GenericBase<T extends String, U>
```

In this example, you can call all methods that String provides plus those of Object, since the type is guaranteed to be String or a subclass (bad example, String has no subclasses).

You could also do something similar for the function in your Application:

```
private static Integer func2(GenericBase<? extends String> genericBase) {
    String field1 = genericBase.getField1();
    return field1.length();
}
```

Problem with this solution is the complete lack of hierarchy between your classes in the example code, making it pretty much impossible to use an upper bound that allows you to call the generic method for multiple types. Perhaps this is less of an issue in your actual code.